# How to console selected and default dropdown value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-select, console.log

I want to console my selected dropdown value onload for that i am using below code its working. but if i change my selection from dropdown then too i want to see my current selected value in console.  By this i can get my current selected value for my next if else operation.

```
var s = document.getElementsByName('org_id')[0];
var value = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

console.log(value);
```

By above code i can get onload selected value. but after that if i change selection from dropdown my console not showing current selected value. How to achieve this with jquery.

```
<select name="org_id" id="org_id" class="required">
    <option value="">--Select Organization--</option>
    <option value="1">ABC</option>
    <option value="2">DEF</option>
    <option value="3">GHI</option>
    <option value="4">JKL</option>
    <option value="5">MNO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you paste html snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Add a `change` event listener to the `<select>` dropdown that will trigger on the change of the `option`
2. You then need to call this listener function explicitly on page load so that you can print the initially selected value.

```js
var s = document.getElementsByName('org_id')[0];

s.addEventListener("change", changeOrg);

function changeOrg(){
  var value = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(value);
}

//on page load
changeOrg();
```

```html
<select name='org_id'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: some how its working but one change i need last selected value should be remove . currenty it shows all values in console